# Where can I find credentials for webmin which was ran in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, credentials, webmin

I've added to my docker compose following service.

```
  webmin:
    image: pschatzmann/webmin
    container_name: webmin
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
```

It has been started successfully and I've opened `http://localhost:10000/` in my browser

but I can't find login/password to get inside.  I tried `admin/admin` and `root/webmin` but no luck

Comment: Can you try root:eraadmin?

Comment: @yahorbarkouski unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a small CTF session, I was able to find the correct logic/password in configs:

```
login=admin
password=
```

So you'll be able to sign in under "admin" without password required :)